# Can I Get the Pids of Exiting (defunct) Processes Programmatically?

Tags: c++, c, fork, waitpid

I'm running into a problem where it'd be really nice to know what processes are exiting before calling `waitpid()` — because I might want to get information from the `/proc` directory on that process, depending on which it is.

I'm curious if there is a programmatic way in C or C++ to get the PIDs of all defunct processes. I know that it is possible to `grep` this information from `ps`, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it programmatically.

Comment: catching `sigchld` perhaps?

Comment: Everything `ps` knows it takes from `/proc`.

Comment: We catch sigchld, and it eventually learns which processes from waitpid(), I'm curious if there's a way to learn this before waitpid() is called.